# How to dynamically change one piece of shape data based on a drop down box

Tags: vba, visio

I have a user form that runs when a cable shape is dropped onto the sheet: The form asks the user whether the cable classification is primary or secondary and whether the tray type is primary or secondary. If, for example a primary cable and tray is chosen, then the cable type+tray shape data will change to drop down lists only containing primary cables and trays.

```
Public shp3 As Shape
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim CableClass As String
   Dim TrayClass As String
   Dim pg2 As Page

   CableClass = ComboBox1.Value
   TrayClass = ComboBox2.Value
   Set shp3 = ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID(cID)

   If CableClass = "Primary" Then
        shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_CableClass.Value").FormulaU = """Primary"""
        shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_CableType.Format").FormulaU = """Cable 1;Cable 
        2;Cable 3;Cable 4"""
   ElseIf CableClass = "Secondary" Then
       shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_CableClass.Value").FormulaU = """Secondary"""
       shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_CableType.Format").FormulaU = """Cable 1;Cable 
       2;Cable 3;Cable 4"""
   End If

   If TrayClass = "Primary" Then
       shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_TrayClass.Value").FormulaU = """Primary"""
       shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_TrayType.Format").FormulaU = """cable tray 
       1;cable tray 2;cable tray 3;cable tray 4"""
   ElseIf TrayClass = "Secondary" Then
       shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_TrayClass.Value").FormulaU = """Secondary"""
       shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_TrayType.Format").FormulaU = """cable tray 
       1;cable tray 2;cable tray 3;cable tray 4"""
   End If
   Unload Me
End Sub
```

Once a specific type of cable or tray is chosen from the shape data, I want the cost to automatically change based on what is selected. In other words, I want one piece of shape data (cost) to change dynamically based on the type of cable selected from a drop down box.

Comment: You've already got the `If...Then` logic to determine your cable class and tray class, simply add some code in each portion to set the cost in each area. You've given us no indication of how you're storing the cost data, so it will be up to you to determine where to store it and how to change it (percentage change? lookup from a cost table? who know...)

Comment: The if statement determines whether a primary or secondary class is chosen. From this the cable type shape data changes to a list box containing either primary or secondary cables. Another shape data parameter is cost. Once the user selects a specific cable, I want the cost parameter to change.

Comment: Then I would think you'd want a line similar to this `shp3.Cells("Prop.Row_CableClass.Value").FormulaU = """Primary"""` that would set the appropriate shape data parameter to the appropriate cost.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I'm not sure how to get this code to run as the result of the user changing the shape data.

Comment: potentially [`Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/dependent-combo-boxes.html)

Comment: Ok so will that sub be called automatically when any list box is changed?

Comment: @Kamran64 the `_change()` routine will be called when the specified `ComboBox` is changed. Write one routine that does the processing, pass it the ComboBox as a paramenter, then call that routine for each ComboBox that needs this processing. That way you have only one place to fix the code when it's broken or needs to be updated

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but much too long/complex for just a comment:

In your user form code behind:

```
Private Sub CableClass_Change() 
  SetCableClassValues CableClass, shape
End Sub

Private Sub TrayClass_Change() 
  SetTrayClassValues TrayClass, shape
End Sub
```

In a separate Standard Module:

```
Public Sub SetCableClassValues (ByVal cableClass as ComboBox, ByVal theShape as Visio.Shape)
  theShape.Cells("Prop.Row_CableClass.Value").FormulaU = """Primary"""
  theShape.... 'set the appropriate cost value here
End Sub

Public Sub SetTrayClassValues (ByVal trayClass as ComboBox, ByVal theShape as Visio.Shape)
  theShape.Cells("Prop.Row_CableClass.Value").FormulaU = """Primary"""
  theShape.... 'set the appropriate cost value here
End Sub
```

Note that is all "air-coding" so it won't work exactly as written. Once you're in the `SetCableClassValues` routine, though, you'll have access to everything in the `cableClass` combo box, just as if you were directly in the code-behind. You'll also have access to `theShape` - whichever one it is that you have as `shp3` in your existing code which you'll pass in as the `shape` parameter.

If you need both bits of info to determine the costing, then you'll have 1 routine that will take both comboboxen and the shape as parameters, ensure both have valid values selected, then do all the updating.

I'm not at all familiar with the Visio object model, so you'll have to figure out how to set the cost, but it looks like you've got enough understanding to handle that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do some powerful things in the `ShapeSheet` without having to resort to VBA. You can force the question (input of data) on shape drop, and then use the properties (`Prop.x`, `User.x`) to set up your drop down lists.

Looking at your provided code, you are following the same sort of actions as you would in the `ShapeSheet`, just using a different syntax/language/interface. The logic is similar, you set up a `User` property (or rather two, because you are looking at cables and trays) that returns true or false depending on whether you have "Primary" or "Secondary" selected. You then use that `Boolean` result to return the appropriate string of choices.

I don't have Visio on this machine to provide a specific example - I have used this technique to change colours of shapes and even change the geometries.